# how to call the code behind method in java script for button onclick event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to fire this method when I click on button through javascript/jquery

this is my webmethod,

```
 [WebMethod] 
public static string haldlescrolling(string name, string address)
{
    String str = string.Empty;

    httpWebRequest2 =             (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ws.vidlib.com/video/list");
    httpWebRequest2.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest2.Method = "POST";

    int start1 = start + 10;

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest2.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        int max1 = max + 10;
        max = max + 10;
        string more = "{\"StartRowIndex\":\"" + start + "\",\"MaximumRows\":\"" + max + "\"}";
       // string json2 = js + more;
        streamWriter.Write(more);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest2.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            l1 = (List<Test>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result, typeof(List<Test>));
            for (int i = 0; i < l1.Count; i++)
            {
                str = str + "<img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/movingmediapurchase/thumbnail/48748.jpg' />";
                string video_id = l1[i].ClipId.ToString();
                str = str + "<div id='parent'  style=\"position:relative; float:left; text-align: top;\" onmouseover='callMouseOver(\"" + video_id + "\")' onmouseout='callMouseOut(\"" + video_id + "\")' ><a href='" + l1[i].PreviewUrl.ToString() + "' class='html5lightbox' data-width='450' data-height='350'><img src='" + l1[i].ThumbnailUrl.ToString() + "' class ='thumbnail'/></a><div id='" + video_id + "' style='display: none;position: absolute; z-index:10000; top: 110px; left:30px ; height: 34px;'><img src='tweetbutton.png'/><img src ='small-facebook-like-butto.gif' /><img src='pinit-button.png' /></div></div>" + "&nbsp;";

                /*
                Label1.Text = l1.Count.ToString();
                Image1.ImageUrl = l1[0].ThumbnailUrl.ToString();
                Label1.Text = l1[0].ThumbnailUrl.ToString();
                 * 
                 */
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

How to create javascript method to call the above code behind method?

Comment: go do homework on Ajax,json.. it will really help you in future..

Comment: No idea why this question is downvoted. It is clear (even if the asker isn't native English speaker) and includes code (so we know the problem isn't the C# code). It might be a duplicate though. But for a downvote, it's best to add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some javascript code like this, if you're using jQuery (which I would recommend in your case):

```
$(function() {
    $('#idOfButton').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/haldlescrolling",
            data: "{name: 'name', address: 'address'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                // do something on success
                $('#idOfDiv').html(msg.d);
            },
            error: function() {
                // do something on error
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The first line indicates a function will be executed when the DOM is loaded:

```
$(function() {});
```

The second line attaches an event handler to the click event of the button with id `idOfButton`:

```
$('#idOfButton').click(function() {});
```

The `$.ajax()` call is a method from jQuery (see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) to make ajax calls easier.

The code above is not pure javascript, but relies on jQuery. jQuery is a library that can make your javascript code easier and more readable. I definitely recommend you use it, but there are other libraries out there.